# Why does dividing zero by a number using repeated subtraction doesn't work?

Tags: arithmetic

I know that division can be represented as repeated subtraction, or as an opposite of multiplication.

For example, if we divide 6 by 2, we can say what number is multiplied by 2 gives us 6?, which in this case is number 3, and 3 is considered unique in this particular example because it is the only number that equals 6 divided by 2.

if I want to represent that same example as repeated subtraction, we say 6-2-2-2 = 0.

if we're dividing 0 by 6 using the same analogy, for example with multiplication 0 divided by 6 = 0, and 6*0 equal 0.

but when I use repeated subtraction and say 0-6 = (-6)- (6) = -12 … and so on we never reach zero, basically -∞.

So what I am missing here?
Thank you.

Comment: How many times do you have to remove $6$ from $0$ to get to $0$? The answer is $0$.

Comment: Repeated subtraction is derived from the fact that: Given x/y = z, we have x - zy = 0 where z*y = z + z + z+.... y many times. So, 6/2 = 3 implies 6 - 2(3) = 0 and 6 - 2 -2 -2 = 0. In the zero case 0/6= z becomes 0 - 6*z = 0,  z = 0.

Comment: When you gave "6-2-2-2 = 0" , why did you stop there ? Why did you not give "6-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2.... = -∞" ? Well , you might say , you stopped when "Encountering" ZERO. Eg "15 = 15" & "15-5 = 10" & "15-5-5 = 5" & "15-5-5-5 = ZERO" , hence 15/5 = 3. Well , then , when we want 0/6 , we already have "0 = ZERO" , hence no more calculations are required here , we do not have to make "0-6 = -6" , we did the subtraction ZERO times , hence the Answer is ZERO ! !

Answer (score 1):

you are defining division as the number of times one number is subtracted by another *until* zero or less is obtained.

The number of times $0$ is subtacted by $6$ until zero or less is obtained is $0$ because subtracting $0$ by $6$ even once results in $-6$